# Theme.Dialog with seekbar android 4 style

Tags: android, dialog, seekbar

I have an activity as Dialog (`"@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`) displaying a Seekbar. However, the style for the seekbar on android 4.x devices is not the holo style. I am getting a seekbar as in the image below

[image]

How can I do to display the holo seekbar on devices android 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

Comment: I already had set up the SDK versions on the Manifest file, but unfortunately, it does not work due to I have the activity as a Dialog using "@android:style/Theme.Dialog" (which is not Holo.Light.Dialog)

Comment: As you said you use Theme.Dialog.  
Why don't you use Theme.Holo.Dialog?  
if you have see the framework.apk in rom.  
you can see both Holo and old version resource.  
they are both in framework.apk
when you use Theme.Dialog,it will use the old style Dialog.  
if you use Theme.Holo.Dialog,you will use the Holo.  
you can also use HoloEverywhere to show the Holo before Android 3.0.

Comment: I cannot use the "Theme.Holo.Dialog" because it requires API level 11 and my minSdkVersion is 8. I wanted make it simple, so I dont want to use the HoloEverywhere, I want to display the old Dialog style for versions lower than 11 and the Holo Dialog for versions greater than 11.

Comment: You just change the compiled sdk version to 4.0 and use the Theme.Holo will do what you want. There will be nothing to change. The IDE will take care of the api level.